# How to dowload images from firebase to an ImageView

Tags: android, firebase

Hi EveryOne i want to set an image from firebase in an imageview i ve tried a code suggested by google but i have a problem with GlideApp and the image do not show

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
   StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference() 
// ImageView in your Activity
   ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
   GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
    .load(storageReference)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a path to the image that inside `Cloud storage`, something like this:

```
   storageReference.child(/some_images/path).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Glide
                            .with(this) 
                            .load(uri) // pass the image url
                            .into(imageView); ed
                }
            });
```

Comment: If it works please accept the answer to it can help others with the same problem.